# Blotchy clear coat water based poly on natural finish

Tags: finishing

I’m doing a refinishing project  for someone and I’ve ran into quite an issue. The color of the wood is not coming out evenly. I’ve only applied one coat for the most part and am starting to sanding in between coats. The color however is still blotchy. What can I do to fix this? I’ve had to resand a good portion of this already. i am afraid if it doing the same thing. I am not applying heavy and you can clearly see the color difference from any angle. It seems to be the wood color. Like the wood isn’t taking the clearcoat the same. I can possibly sand it down anymore. Please help cuz I’m at a loss in how to fix this?

Comment: What wood is it? If you don't know the species what type, hardwood or softwood (conifer wood)? Softwoods, and the occasional hardwood, are noted for their tendency to blotch. But because this is a refinishing job there's every chance that it's not the wood itself that's the cause but remaining traces of the original finish here and there, it's incredibly easy to leave some behind particularly if stripper was not used. I think this is especially likely here based on you using a waterbased finish, since this should colour wood minimally or not at all. BTW pics would help!

Comment: FFR when refinishing something when you're done and you're back to bare wood (or think you are) it's a very good idea to go over the entire surface with water or white spirit and see how the wood looks. This previews how the wood will be wetted with finish, so you're looking for light spots where the wood doesn't look like it has become wet — these are literally dry spots, where remaining finish (which can be IN the wood, not more easily visible on the surface) has prevented the liquid from wetting the wood fibres.